# MaterializeCSS - Dropdown doesn't show at the right place

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS in my project.
I want to make a button with a dropdown attached.
When I click on the button, the dropdown is not showing at the right place : it shows at the start of the table instead of below or on top of the button trigger.

Here is a fiddle that reproduce the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/f62ssr8f/

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>More</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="details">
Test1                               
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="details">
Test2                                    
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="details">
Test3                                      
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="details">
Test4                                   
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<ul id="details" class="dropdown-content">
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test2</li>
</ul>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are your buttons in a `table`? ***Also note that your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a  `ul` as a child of `tbody`.***

Comment: I tried to replicate what I have in my code. I have multiple lines in a table, each with a button triggering a different dropdown. For the example, I just made one dropdown but I have the same behavior in my code. I also tried to move the dropdown out of the `table` with no success.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Please check this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/f62ssr8f/5/

Comment: I'm not saying your problem is related to you using a table. I'm sensing layout tables.

Comment: @acmsohail It's exactly what I need but I don't see where are the changes to the code

Comment: @KristenJoseph-Delaffon don't include your references inside the HTML on jsfiddle. I added to the left section. Also, I called the jquery library 2.1.3 on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try another jquery version(3.2.1)

https://jsfiddle.net/f62ssr8f/23/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```